# How to stop or pause glutTimerFunc in GLUT?

Tags: opengl, glut

In my project i'm running a train which stops moving when it reaches a particular point this moving is carried out by glutTimerFunc .I once again want the train to start from the location where i click my mouse to a particular location 
                            BUT THE PROBLEM HERE IS,
My timer still running even after reaching that location,so even when i initialise the starting point its not working(it continues from the left location).

Now i need to stop the timer and start the train timer for the new location.

Comment: Do you have to use glutTimerFunc, or can you use your own timer instead?

Answer (score 3):

The [API documentation](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html) has the following to say:

> There is no support for canceling a registered callback. Instead, ignore a callback based on its value parameter when it is triggered.

So, add a boolean to your software and ignore the event whenever it is triggered. It would be better to use a clock-based timer rather than an event-driven timer and do your timed updates manually everytime the main loop runs (you detect the amount of time since the last update, and you determine whether to perform an update tick(s)), in the long run however. This is how physics and various other time-based simulations are handled in most professional software, using the event-driven model sets you up to miss or frequently wind up handling a timed event excessively late.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of game engines and actors.

My recommendation is that you don't try to do this by turning glutTimerFunc on or off directly. The timer function should be the top level "heartbeat" for the entire program, and it's job is just to tell every object that has behaviour - an "actor" - that it should update itself. The train should have its own internal state that knows where it is and whether it should be moving or not.